# How to use Method Reference operator to get the reference of method

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I want to reference an annotation value in one class from another class. Like here -

```
class A {
    private static final String STATIC_STRING = B.class.getMethod("myMethod").getAnnotation(SomeAnnotation.class).name();
}
```

The problem here is that I cannot use this syntax because it requires `getMethod` to be wrapped in a `try-catch` which is not possible. Although I can use a `static` block to create this variable and just gulp the exception in `catch` block, I don't want to do that because if in future the method name is changed, compiler won't throw an error in the `static` block.

I was wondering if I could do something like

```
private static final String STATIC_STRING = (B::myMethod).getAnnotation(SomeAnnotation.class).name();
```

Note: neither `B` nor `SomeAnnotation` is my source, they come from another library.

**I have 2 questions here**

- Is there a better way to get value from annotation, preferably without using any external library like Google Reflections or similar?
- How can I use `::` to get instance of `java.lang.reflect.Method`? Is it possible altogether? If yes, is vice-versa also possible, i.e. create supplier or mapper from `Method`'s object?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, have you considered using a getter?

```
private static String getSomeAnnotationName() {
    try {
        return B.class.getMethod("myMethod").getAnnotation(SomeAnnotation.class).name();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

For your second question, I don't think getting a `Method` from `::` is possible. This is because methods got from `::` represent implementations  of functional interfaces, not really methods. However, the reverse is possible. You can create a lambda like this:

```
Consumer<SomeType> consumer = x -> {
    try {
        yourMethod.invoke(someObject, x)
    } catch (...) {
        // again you have to ignore the exceptions here, unfortunately
    }
};
```

Comment: this does not solve the problem as I would still get compile error because of the `throws` declaration.

Comment: @Mukund You gotta handle the exception somehow. I have edited the answer to return null when an exception is thrown. Is that good enough?

Comment: Thanks for the edit but I didn't want to do such a thing as I already mentioned in the question (although I talked about a static block, the approach is pretty similar)

Comment: What I am basically expecting is a straight forward way of accessing a particular class's particular method's `Method` object verified at compile time.

Comment: @Mukund I don't think that is possible in Java. You can try searching "Java Compile Time Reflection" and see what comes out.